# How do I remove the space between the last paragraph and the bibliography?

Tags: spacing

This MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{citations.bib}
@article{hansen1982large,
  title={Large sample properties of generalized method of moments estimators},
  author={Hansen, Lars Peter},
  journal={Econometrica: Journal of the Econometric Society},
  pages={1029--1054},
  year={1982},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}

@article{tauchen1986finite,
  title={Finite state markov-chain approximations to univariate and vector autoregressions},
  author={Tauchen, George},
  journal={Economics letters},
  volume={20},
  number={2},
  pages={177--181},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*0.2}{*0.2}
\titleformat{\section} {\normalsize \bfseries} {\thesection}{1em}{}
\renewcommand \refname{}
\renewcommand\bibsection{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\nocite{tauchen1986finite}
\section{Model}
\lipsum[2]
\nocite{hansen1982large}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{citations}
\end{document}
```

produces output like this (some of which is snipped):

[image: incorrect spacing]

How do I change or remove the spacing between this last paragraph and the start of the bibliography? I'm preparing something with tight space constraints, so I'd like to shrink this to see if that saves me (maybe) one line at the end. (I can't touch the margins, font, or spacing between other lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather on the inelegant side, but you can use `\vspace` with a negative value right above your `\bibliography` command to accomplish this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{citations.bib}
@article{hansen1982large,
  title={Large sample properties of generalized method of moments estimators},
  author={Hansen, Lars Peter},
  journal={Econometrica: Journal of the Econometric Society},
  pages={1029--1054},
  year={1982},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}

@article{tauchen1986finite,
  title={Finite state markov-chain approximations to univariate and vector autoregressions},
  author={Tauchen, George},
  journal={Economics letters},
  volume={20},
  number={2},
  pages={177--181},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*0.2}{*0.2}
\titleformat{\section} {\normalsize \bfseries} {\thesection}{1em}{}
\renewcommand \refname{}
\renewcommand\bibsection{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\nocite{tauchen1986finite}
\section{Model}
\lipsum[2]
\nocite{hansen1982large}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\vspace{-8pt}
\bibliography{citations}
\end{document}
```

[image: example pic]

Answer (score 2):

A completely different approach. You want to save SOME vertical space. Instead of removing it before bibliography, which gives an unpleasant effect, you can use TeX command `\looseness`. If you write

> \looseness-1
>   Your (rather long) paragraph,

TeX tries to produce one line shorter paragraph.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the tip; this didn't work in my case, but I think that's because I've already tried to reduce the space as much as possible (with single spaced lines, french spacing, etc.). I'll remember this for the future.